# Maximum call stack size exceeded in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, react-async

I am using react native and everything was working fine until I introduced following libs in package.json

```
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
```

Also updated .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react-native", "babel-preset-stage-3"]
}
```

But now I m receiving **Maximum call stack size exceeded** while running application. I added above dependencies to get async/await functions.

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "pilbara_weed_management_mobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.2",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-smart-splash-screen": "^2.3.5",
    "react-native-snackbar-dialog": "^1.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "3.0.1",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I am still getting same error even after removing dependencies. Any idea what went wrong?
[image]

Comment: Was your app working as expected before the update to your package.json?

Comment: @Chris yep 100% with charm. :)

Comment: can you upload your codes of app?

Comment: this error is usually because of bad using of a function in an event call like `onPress`.

Comment: @VahidBoreiri didn't write/change any function

Comment: This is normally to do with setting state inside a render function i'd make sure to check your components

Answer (score 0):

some of these are included already by `react` & `react-native` and makes an infinite loop also `async/await`  functions is included in `react native` without adding extra dependencies